# py2app is not copying the Python.framework to the new app while using virutalenv

Tags: python, osx-lion, virtualenv, pyobjc, py2app

environment: MacOS X 10.7.2, system installed python 2.7.1, virtualenv 1.7.2, pyobjc 2.3, py2app 0.6.4+

I have a newly created virtualenv with pyobc 2.3 and py2app installed.
When I run python setup.py py2app to create an app (for example in py2app/examples/simple) everything seems to compile and it does produce a double clickable app, but after clicking on that app I get the following error:

```
A Python runtime not could be located.  You may need to install a framework build of Python, or edit the PyRuntimeLocations array in this application's Info.plist file.
```

However, if i follow the same process in the standard install of Lion. The app functions well and as expected.

Any suggestions on how I can make virtualenv and py2app play nicely with one another?

Thanks!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`py2app` never copies a system Python into an app bundle that it produces.  If you want to make a standalone app that can be deployed on multiple versions of OS X, you need to use `py2app` with a separately-installed Python, like from a python.org installer.  See, for example, [Py2App Can't find standard modules](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1346297/py2app-cant-find-standard-modules)

Comment: Thank you for you help. I installed python 2.7 from with brew and edit my PATH accordingly. I can now build/compile the py2app/examples/simple and hopefully much more. Thanks again.

Comment: Ned, I have built within a pyenv which downloaded it's own 2.6 Python (within the pyenv, `which python` returns */Users/Pyderman/.pyenv/shims/python*), yet am encountering the same issue: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34845112/do-py2app-built-apps-require-a-python-installation

Comment: Hi Ned/macdhuibh,  could you please let me know where did you updated the path and which exact path you updated  ?