# PY2APP- How to convert semi-standalone app to 100% standalone

Tags: python, macos, py2app

I am developing an app using py2app. In app deveoped by py2app, Its Frameworks is empty, and in MacOS gives the shortcut to python of /user/bin. So, it does not contains python of itself. When I run this app on other system in which python is not installed, this app showing error. I had gone through [py2app is not copying the Python.framework to the new app while using virutalenv](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10184974/py2app-is-not-copying-the-python-framework-to-the-new-app-while-using-virutalenv). But I didn't understand it, I am new to mac.I want my app to run on any system whether python installed or not. I am using python 2.7 and osx 10.8.2. Please suggest steps in easy way.

Comment: Do you use Apple's build of Python or some other build (homebrew, python.org installer, …)?  Py2app will not create a standalone bundle when you use Apple's build of Python.

Comment: I used Active python 2.7.5.6 for my python environment.

Comment: I am using a python.org install within **pyenv**, but am encountering the same issue: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34845112/do-py2app-built-apps-require-a-python-installation