# How do I use py2app with a virtual environment?

Tags: python, tkinter, py2app

I'm trying to create an app with py2app and a simple Tkinter Python 3 program. My setup.py file is the default one created when running the py2applet --make-setup command. When I try to build the app, numerous files are copied to the app bundle but I get the this error: `error: can't copy '/Users/bill/.virtualenvs/tk3/Resources/Python.app/Contents/MacOS/Python': doesn't exist or not a regular file`. And when I try to open the built app, I get a dialog window with

> A Python runtime could not be located. You may need to install a
>   framework build of Python or edit the PyRuntimeLocations array in this
>   application's Info.plist file.

I installed Python 3 with homebrew.

Comment: [py2app is not copying the python framework to the new app while using virutalenv](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10184974/py2app-is-not-copying-the-python-framework-to-the-new-app-while-using-virutalenv)

Comment: @kums: Thanks, that's exactly what the issue was. Running the command `python3 setup.py py2app` outside the virtual environment copied the python framework successfully.