# How do I use py2app with Anaconda python?

Tags: python, macos, anaconda, py2app

I am using Python 3 from the Anaconda distribution, and trying to convert a simple python program into an OS X app (running on El Capitan). Following the instructions in [the tutorial](https://pythonhosted.org/py2app/tutorial.html), I ran

```
py2applet --make-setup my-script.py
python setup.py py2app -A
```

Everything ran fine with no errors, but when I try to launch the app, I get this error message:

> my-script: A python runtime not could (sic) be located. You may need to install a framework build of Python, or edit the PyRuntimeLocations array in this applications Info.plist file.

I understood this to mean I should add the path of Anaconda's python (which is  in my bash PATH, but is not known to the launcher). However, the app's automatically generated `Info.plist` already points to the Anaconda python binary:

```
<key>PythonInfoDict</key>
<dict>
    <key>PythonExecutable</key>
    <string>/Applications/Experimental/anaconda/bin/python</string>
    ...
```

I don't see what there is to fix here. I have read these related questions:

- [How do I use py2app with a virtual environment?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26081258/699305)
- [py2app is not copying the python framework to the new app while using virutalenv](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10184974/py2app-is-not-copying-the-python-framework-to-the-new-app-while-using-virutalenv)

The first question involves the same error message, and is resolved by following the advice in the second question. But as I understand it, these questions describe the opposite situation: The OP was running a python distributed with the OS, and wanted to distribute their app; the solution is to use a separately installed python. I *am* using a non-system python, and I'm not yet trying to distribute anything. So what is causing the trouble here, and what is the solution?

Comment: Have you tried running the app without using the alias option (eg. `python setup.py py2app`), or by `open -a dist/MyApplication.app`?

Comment: Useful suggestion! `open -a dist/my-script.app` fails ("Unable to find application named 'dist/my-open.app'"), but trying a full app build (still doesn't work but) flushed out the problem: The `libpython` dll is not named as py2app expects. I was able to fix it by editing the generated `Info.plist`.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The suggestion by @l'L'l allowed me to identify the problem: While there were no errors when I generated my app in "alias mode" (using symlinks to the environment instead of copying binaries), building the app without alias mode flushed out the error: `py2app` looks for the `libpython` DLL under the non-existent name `/Applications/anaconda/lib/libpython3.4.dylib`.

A quick check showed that Anaconda provides this DLL under a slightly different name: `libpython3.4m.dylib`. While patching `dist/my-script.app/Contents/Info.plist` fixes the problem, the *right* solution is to edit `setup.py` so that future builds will work correctly. With the help of the [py2app documentation](http://py2app.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tweaking.html), I put together the following (partial contents of `setup.py` shown):

```
OPTIONS = {'argv_emulation': True,
           'plist': {
               'PyRuntimeLocations': [
                '@executable_path/../Frameworks/libpython3.4m.dylib',
                '/Applications/anaconda/lib/libpython3.4m.dylib'
               ]
           }}

setup(
    app=APP,
    data_files=DATA_FILES,
    options={'py2app': OPTIONS},
    setup_requires=['py2app'],
)
```

The paths come from the generated `Info.plist`; I only modified the absolute path, reasoning that if I ever provide a local DLL at the relative path, it will have the default name.

Comment: How did you find both of those DLLs?  I have the same problem, and tried including the one DLL I could find in the PyRuntimeLocations: /Users/***/anaconda/lib/libpython3.5m.dylib.  It doesn't seem to make a difference, though.  In fact, I tried including /Users/***/anaconda/lib/nonsense.dylib and nothing changed, no error was thrown.

Comment: I just `cd`'d to the directory that would have contained the file `py2app` tried to include, and checked what else is there. But you could also try `mdfind -name libpython` (if you're on OS X; otherwise it's `locate` or `slocate`, I guess). But you're saying you didn't actually see the error I describe in my answer? Did you try building in non-alias mode? If you did and you're not getting the error message, you probably have a different problem.

Comment: To clarify: I get the same error that you got, and am building in non-alias mode.  py2app also gives this error message while compiling:  `ValueError: '/Users/***/anaconda/lib/libpython3.5.dylib' does not exist`
But py2app gives me that same error no matter what I put in  'plist', i.e.: `{'PyRuntimeLocations': ['/Users/****/anaconda/lib/nonsense.dylib']}`.  And then gives me the "edit the PyRuntimeLocations" error when I try to open it.  So it doesn't seem like it is actually using the PyRuntimeLocations.  I was wondering how you got PyRuntimeLocations to actually work.

Comment: I got it to work by putting in the path to a DLL that does actually exist. If you edit `setup.py`, you need to rerun `py2app` (i.e. `python setup.py py2app`).

Comment: You must be confused about _something_, because of course writing a nonsense name will give you the same error as the file inserted automatically: Neither file exists. And in your first comment you say "nothing changed, no error was thrown"... so not sure what you're actually doing. Double- and triple-check that you provided the library name correctly. (Example only: Maybe there's an accent in your user name, opening the door to encoding issues?) Anyway I only saw the error when I tried to open the app with `open -a`, not at build time.

Comment: When I try this solution, I edited my setup.py to include my anaconda3 version of libpython3.6m.dylib but it continues to give me the starting error message: "ValueError: '/anaconda3/lib/libpython3.6.dylib' does not exist"
What did you do to know setup.py's path was being executed.

Comment: I can't say I remember, exactly; I looked at the py2app [documentation](http://py2app.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tweaking.html) and studied the generated `setup.py`. I knew it was being read when either the symptoms or the error message changed. (By the way the link to the documentation in my answer was stale; if you didn't bother to find the right doc yet, try again.)

Comment: PS You did re-run `python setup.py py2app` after you edited `setup.py`, right? ...

Comment: Yup! It wouldn't get through execution anyway, so I would need to in order to have something to try to run. I added a symbolic link between libpython3.6m and libpython3.6 and got the setup to complete, but now I still have the "fatal termination no python" error when I try to click the app.