# cx_freeze does not find python 3 path mac

Tags: macos, python-3.x, pyqt, cx-freeze

I have this problem when I try to generate an app executable. I follow this [example](http://www.pythonschool.net/pyqt/distributing-your-application-on-mac-os-x/) so the code for the setup would be

```
application_title = "app_name" #what you want to application to be called
main_python_file = "main.py" #the name of the python file you use to run the program

import sys

from cx_Freeze import setup, Executable

base = None
if sys.platform == "win32":
    base = "Win32GUI"

includes = ["atexit","re"]

setup(
        name = application_title,
        version = "0.1",
        description = "Sample cx_Freeze PyQt4 script",
        options = {"build_exe" : {"includes" : includes }},
        executables = [Executable(main_python_file, base = base)])
```

then I go to my terminal and press

```
python setup.py bdist_mac
```

for some reason that I do not know how to solve I get this output, and the file it is not generated

```
running bdist_mac
running build
running build_exe
copying /Applications/anaconda/lib/python3.4/site-packages/cx_Freeze/bases/Console -> build/exe.macosx-10.5-x86_64-3.4/main
copying /opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/Python -> build/exe.macosx-10.5-x86_64-3.4/Python
error: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/Python'
```

I have installed anaconda with Python 3.4 and cx_freeze. Any suggestions?

Comment: This doesn't appear to have anything to do with PyQt, Rather it appears that cx_feeze isn't finding the Python install correctly. The release notes for v4.3.3 states that some OSX path resolution problems have been fixed. If you aren't using cx_freeze 4.3.3 I would suggest updating!

Comment: I already have installed the cx_freeze 4.3.3 package, what else could it be? `@three_pineapples`

Comment: `@AlperTokgöz` I gave up with this problem, maybe it is a bug with Yosemite.

Answer (score 1):

I met the same problem and it is fixed by installing a separated python besides anaconda. It seems to be similar with the problem here

[py2app is not copying the Python.framework to the new app while using virutalenv](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10184974/py2app-is-not-copying-the-python-framework-to-the-new-app-while-using-virutalenv)