# "Python runtime could not be located" for py2app standalone build

Tags: python, software-distribution, py2app

I'm attempting to turn a short Python program that I wrote into an easily-distributable application file for OS X, using [py2app](https://py2app.readthedocs.io/en/latest/). I made it through the py2app tutorial, but when I click on my application file the following dialogue is shown:

> A Python runtime not could be located.  You may need to install a
> framework build of Python, or edit the PyRuntimeLocations array in
> this application's Info.plist file.

I'm not sure whether this is helpful, but clicking "Open Console" from that dialogue shows the following errors:

- `LaunchServices: Could not store lsd-identifiers file at /private/var/db/lsd/com.apple.lsdschemes.plist`
- `launchservicesd[83]: SecTaskLoadEntitlements failed error=22`
- `appleeventsd[53]: SecTaskLoadEntitlements failed error=22 11/27/16 7:29:19.787 PM`
- `sharedfilelistd[307]: SecTaskLoadEntitlements failed error=22`

I know that if [py2app uses a "system" version of Python to produce an app, it won't include that Python in the distribution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10184974/py2app-is-not-copying-the-python-framework-to-the-new-app-while-using-virutalenv). However, entering `$` which python in the terminal directs me to my anaconda installation, so that doesn't seem to be the issue.

This is my first time attempting to create a piece of software, so apologies in advance for any obvious missteps. Any help would be greatly appreciated, as I've been banging my head on this all day.