# Py2app for MacOS 'A Python runtime not could be located'

Tags: python, selenium, py2app

I am trying to create an independent application that I built to automate whatsapp messages, however I encountered this message upon after creating the -A file.

This is the setup.py file, I named my .py file to 'Whatsapp Automation.py'

```
from setuptools import setup

APP = ['Whatsapp Automation.py']

OPTIONS = {
 'iconfile':'Whatsapp Automation.icns',
 'argv_emulation': True,
 'packages': ['certifi'],
}

setup(
    app=APP,
    # data_files=DATA_FILES,
    options={'py2app': OPTIONS},
    setup_requires=['py2app'],
)
```

Creation of Alias

```
python setup.py py2app -A
```

After running this, I get the error as seen in the image below

```
 ./dist/Whatsapp\ Automation.app/Contents/MacOS/Whatsapp\ Automation
```

[image]

For more info, these are all my imports in the Whatsapp Automation.py file, do i need to include them in the setup.py file?

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import *
import tkinter.filedialog as filedialog
from tkinter.filedialog import askopenfilename

from time import sleep
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
import socket
```

I understand that a similar question has been posted however there has been no answer for that so I thought I'd post one again. Hopefully someone would be able to help, thanks!

Comment: What version of Python are you using? Are you using a virtual environment?

Comment: Does this [discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10184974/py2app-is-not-copying-the-python-framework-to-the-new-app-while-using-virutalenv) helps you?