# I'm trying to build an stand alone application of my python code by using py2app but there's a error when I open the app

Tags: python, macos, py2app

I've not yet converted the app to standalone.
so I've made my dist and built and my app is showing in the finder but when i open it and error comes [error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y9aJC.png)

the error says:

> survey(name of application) has encountered a fatal error, and will now terminate.

I created a virtual environment in python3 in my iterm2 and it built the app. I followed [this link to convert my python script to MacOS application](http://www.marinamele.com/from-a-python-script-to-a-portable-mac-application-with-py2app)

this is what i did in my iterm2 terminal

```
python3 -m venv final
source final/bin/activate
```

after this i follow the instructions of [this link](http://www.marinamele.com/from-a-python-script-to-a-portable-mac-application-with-py2app)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [py2app is not copying the Python.framework to the new app while using virutalenv](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10184974/py2app-is-not-copying-the-python-framework-to-the-new-app-while-using-virutalenv)

Comment: i saw the answer to this question but i don't know how to do all those steps in standalone version of python like creating venv or downloading it cause it doesn't take pip as a command

Comment: search for same steps for macOS