# py2app with pyenv - A Python runtime not could be located

Tags: python, pyenv, py2app

### Problem

I use `pyenv`. I have a virtual environment activated in my working directory (with Python version `3.10.0`).

Following the tutorial [here](https://py2app.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tutorial.html), after doing the command

```
python setup.py py2app -A
```

and trying to run my application for the first time (from the folder `dist`), this error occurs:

> A Python runtime not could be located.  You may need to install a framework build of Python, or edit the PyRuntimeLocations array in this application's Info.plist file.

--

##### Note

The file `dist/myapp.app/Contents/Info.plist` has the following lines:

```
<key>PyRuntimeLocations</key>
<array>
    <string>@executable_path/../Frameworks/libpython3.10.dylib</string>
    <string>/Users/Vladimir/.pyenv/versions/3.10.0/lib/libpython3.10.dylib</string>
```

However, this file `/Users/Vladimir/.pyenv/versions/3.10.0/lib/libpython3.10.dylib` does not even exist:

here is the result of `ls /Users/Vladimir/.pyenv/versions/3.10.0/lib/`:

```
libpython3.10.a    pkgconfig    python3.10
```

---

### Attempted solution

After seeing [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10184974/py2app-is-not-copying-the-python-framework-to-the-new-app-while-using-virutalenv?noredirect=1&lq=1) answer, I tried to install Python from [python.org](https://python.org), then

`pip3 install py2app`, ... and other packages for my app,

and then did the same procedure from the tutorial, but this time with `python3`.

It worked.

---

### Question

Is there a way to make `py2app` work with `pyenv`?

It's not convenient to have a separate Python installation from [python.org](https://python.org) where you would have to re-download all your packages for your project, and also give up the possibility of having different environments for different Python projects.

Comment: Note: there may be [better packaging tools](https://pyoxidizer.readthedocs.io/en/stable/pyoxidizer_comparisons.html) than py2app, e.g. PyInstaller, PyOxidizer